# Automation in Perl script

Tags: perl, scripting

I am running a perl script. In my perl script, I check the current date and the folder name(which is also in the date format like for example 11-12-07). This perl script run automatically when It checks the curent date with the folder name. The folder is a tar folder which is loaded from other server.

So, basically I need to run the script if it matched with the folder name and current date.

Problem: Sometimes, I used to get the folder next day and my perl script checks only for the current date. The folder i get has the name which is previous date (not the current date).So, I need to do processing of the folder manually. I need to automate it in my perl script.

Please suggest me some ideas to make it happen.

Thanks!!

Code for Reference:

```
my $tfilename = 'tarmd5.tar';
my $td = `date '+%y-%m-%d'`;    # date in yy-mm-dd format
chomp ($td);
my $td2 = `date '+%Y%m%d'`;     # date in yyyymmdd format
chomp ($td2);


#
# get directory from command line
$dir = shift;
leave("'$dir' is not a valid directory") unless (-d $dir);
if    ($dir eq '.') {$dir = cwd();}
elsif ($dir !~ /^\//) {$dir = cwd()."/$dir";}


# print out the time
print scalar(localtime()),"\n";


######## This section unpacks transferred data ########
# go to directory for today and find *tar.gz files to copy

my $dday = "$dir/$td";
next unless (-d "$dday");
@gzfiles = glob("$dday/*tar.gz");
foreach $zf(@gzfiles) {
  next if (($zf =~ /BMP/) || ($zf =~ /LG/) || ($zf =~ /MAP/) || ($zf =~ /STR/));
  print "$zf\n";
  ($status,$message) = systemcall("/bin/cp $zf $fdir");
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you want to run the script for all dates that either match the current date or is in the future?

Comment: Actually, I need to check for current date as well as the previous date. Because I miss the data if it comes late.

Comment: folder comes with the original date(either the current date or previous date). If it comes with previous date, I lose the data as my perl script matches the current date only.

Comment: Hi. Notice that I found an error in the code and fixed it. elsif ($dir != /^\//) is incorrect. Should be elsif ($dir !~ /^\//)

Comment: I was using the previous script and it was showing no problem with " elsif ($dir != /^\//) ". ANyways,I have few doubtts and posted it in the comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm) to do the math. I redid the solution as the first was poorly written. Changed `DateTime->today` to `DateTime->now` because one wants the hms portion when converting back to the desired time zone (from 'floating' or 'UTC').
Also used Perl functions instead of shelling out to the Unix system, (date functions, current working directory - cwd, and copy function).

Update: `elsif ($dir != /^\//)` is incorrect. Changed to `elsif ($dir !~ /^\//)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use DateTime;
use File::Copy;

# set to your desired time zone
my $today = DateTime->now( time_zone => "America/New_York" );
my $td = $today->strftime("%y-%m-%d");

# strongly recommended to do date math in the 'floating'/UTC zone
my $yesterday = $today->set_time_zone('floating')->subtract( days => 1);
my $yd = $yesterday->set_time_zone('America/New_York')->strftime("%y-%m-%d");

my $dir = shift or die "Provide path on command line. $!";

if ($dir eq '.') {
    $dir = cwd;
}
elsif ($dir !~ /^\//) {
    $dir = cwd() . "/$dir"; 
}

opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;
my @dir = sort grep {-d and /$td/ || /$yd/} readdir $dh;
closedir $dh or die $!;
@dir or die "Found no date directories. $!";

my $dday = "$dir/$dir[-1]"; # is today unless today not found, then yesterday
my $fdir = '/some/example/path/';    
my @gzfiles = glob("$dday/*tar.gz");

foreach my $zf (@gzfiles) {  
    next if (($zf =~ /BMP/) || ($zf =~ /LG/) || ($zf =~ /MAP/) || ($zf =~ /STR/)); 
    print "$zf\n";
    copy($zf, $fdir) or die "Unable to copy. $!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you..I will try to use it and will check if it is working for me or not. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: OK, hope it works. I found an error in the code (noted in my update above).

Comment: Hi, Actually I found 2 things here: 1. The script checks for the previous date if todays not find. But I need to check if the previous date has already been processed or not so that I donot process it again.  2. This script checks only for the previous date. What if I have to check for the 2 previous days?  Thanks for your help. hope you understand my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all the directory names that match the current day or any previous days? I presume you move the directories somewhere else when they're done being processed.

A good place to start is the [DateTime module](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm).  Getting the current date is easy enough:

```
    my $now = DateTime->now();
```

Then you need to iterate through all directories and pick out the dates you want.  Use "perldoc -f" to lookup opendir(), readdir(), and closedir() for getting the directories. To match them, parse out the day/month/year, and create another DateTime object:

```
    my $dir_date = DateTime->new(
        day => $dir_day,
        month => $dir_month,
        year => $dir_year,
    );
```

Once you have all that together, finding if the given directory is a hit is as easy as:

```
    processDir( $dir_name ) 
        if DateTime->compare( $now, $dir_date ) >= 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but my main purpose is to select the folder. Name of the folder can be "current date" if it reaches my directory on time or the previous date if it reaches next day (=value of current date). In the 2nd case, I lose the data as it doesnot match and I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it wouldn't be simpler with a bash script. If I understand what you are trying to do, it is

- find recent .tar.gz files, with names not containing "BMP", "LG", etc.
- copy these files to another dir ($fdir, which is undefined in your example)

Maybe you could just ignore the whole folder-name problem, and search for files not older than 24 hours?

```
dir=/your/bas/dir
fdir=/your/destination
find $dir -iname "*.tar.gz" -mtime -1 -not \( -name "*BMP*" -o -name "*LG*" -o -name "*MAP*" \) -exec cp "{}" "$fdir" \;
```